# TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, time-series

I build a time series model and tried to predict the results

```
model = ARIMA(df_mat.Total_Issue_quantities, order=(5,0,0))

y_predict_log = model.predict(start=1, end=24, exog=None, dynamic=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use `ARIMA` model from `statsmodels` package you have to fit model before forecasting with it.

Consider a sample time series data,

```
series = [266, 145.9, 183.1, 119.3, 180.3, 168.5, 231.8, 224.5, 192.8, 122.9, 336.5, 185.9, 194.3, 149.5, 210.1, 273.3, 191.4, 287,
226, 303.6, 289.9, 421.6, 264.5, 342.3, 339.7, 440.4, 315.9, 439.3, 401.3, 437.4, 575.5, 407.6, 682, 475.3, 581.3, 646.9]
```

In order to predict with the help of `ARIMA` from `statsmodels` like you want, you have to define the model and fit it like this,

```
model = ARIMA(series, order=(5,0,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
```

Then you have to use the fitted model to make a prediction like this,

```
model_fit.predict(start=1, end=24, exog=None, dynamic=False)

# Output : array([285.26079759, 241.67873214, 188.09176114, 172.71030303,
       151.02883535, 171.42694684, 187.24591603, 222.14251879,
       231.60804343, 200.38894148, 165.46244686, 276.73489965,
       234.58863518, 189.25204514, 175.23997131, 207.32713479,
       259.00583598, 226.21898223, 261.36238407, 255.73519862,
       285.57681894, 310.52631127, 376.59078703, 314.29265595])
```

Answer (score 3):

Missed the model.fit line

```
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First run an adfuller or KPSS test on your series and check whether its stationary or not. If it is then only proceed with ARIMA.
Its always a good practice to divide the the data into train and test .
Sample code :

```
train = df_mat.iloc[1:1390]

test = df_mat.iloc[1390:]

model = ARIMA(train['Total_Issue_quantities'], order = (5,0,4))

model =model.fit()
```

For predicting :

```
start = len(train)

end = len(train)+len(test)-1

pred = model.predict(start =start , end =end)
```

Reason why am showing these steps is if your error is occurred because of the shape what the predictor function accepts would be resolved by this steps.