# TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params' statsmodel ARIMA

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, statsmodels, arima

While training an ARIMA model using statsmodel, I am able to fit my model but unable to predict for future values. On using model.predict(), it gives error, 'params' missing.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

model = sm.tsa.arima.ARIMA(df_day['unique_user'], order=(p,q, 0))
result_ar = model.fit()

model.predict(start=1, end=24)
```

where 'xyz' & 'abc' are integers.
Following the solution at [TypeError: predict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720384/typeerror-predict-missing-1-required-positional-argument-params?fireglass_rsn=true), using model.fit(disp=0) also gives error that unknown parameter 'disp'.

On further investigation, it comes out that

- statsmodel has been changed recently
- the 'params' refers to model params. How to get them?